# How to center texts with different length and have them one under another?

Tags: html, css

I'm mapping over some data and I want to centre everything under one another

```
.center-things{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.imagini-luptatori{
  border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

---------


<div style={{marginTop: '3%'}}  >

      
        {matches.map(({ luptatorUnu,luptatorDoi,  uri, key }) => (

<div  className='center-things' style={{marginTop: '2%', alignItems:'center'}} key={key}>
    
        <p className='nume-luptatori'> {luptatorUnu} </p>
      <img src={uri.luptatorUnu}  className='imagini-luptatori'/>
      <p> - </p>
      <img src={uri.luptatorDoi} className='imagini-luptatori'/>
        <p className='nume-luptatori'> {luptatorDoi} </p>
    
  </div>
```

[image]

How can i align everything one under another?

https://codepen.io/NagatoThaGod/pen/MWGZWjK

Comment: Can you please create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) snippet? You can hardcode images and text, but we need to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Cervuscamelopardalis added a pen https://codepen.io/NagatoThaGod/pen/MWGZWjK

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
.center-things {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.imagini-luptatori {
  border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*new code from here*/
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.nume-luptatori {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 150px;
  line-height: 50px
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="center-things">
  <p class='nume-luptatori'> Charles Oliveira

  </p>
  <img src="https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/mma/players/full/2504169.png&h=80&w=80&scale=crop" class='imagini-luptatori' />
  <p> - </p>
  <img src='https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/mma/players/full/3332412.png&h=80&w=80&scale=crop' class='imagini-luptatori' />
  <p class='nume-luptatori'> Islam Makhachev </p>
</div>




<div class="center-things">
  <p class='nume-luptatori'> Aljamain Sterling

  </p>
  <img src="https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/mma/players/full/2504169.png&h=80&w=80&scale=crop" class='imagini-luptatori' />
  <p> - </p>
  <img src='https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/mma/players/full/3332412.png&h=80&w=80&scale=crop' class='imagini-luptatori' />
  <p class='nume-luptatori'> TJ Dillashaw </p>
</div>

<div class="center-things">
  <p class='nume-luptatori'> Petr Yan

  </p>
  <img src="https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/mma/players/full/2504169.png&h=80&w=80&scale=crop" class='imagini-luptatori' />
  <p> - </p>
  <img src='https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/mma/players/full/3332412.png&h=80&w=80&scale=crop' class='imagini-luptatori' />
  <p class='nume-luptatori'> Sean O'Malley </p>
</div>
```